Well-posedness of PDE with $\partial_{tt}\Delta u$ - like term
I am looking for direct hints or references for the establishment of existence of suitable weak solutions admitted by a class of problems of the following type: We search $u$ satisfying
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_{tt} L u + M u = 0 \quad\text{on } \mathcal{T}\times \Omega\\
u=g(x) \quad\ \text{on } \{0\}\times \Omega\\
u=h(t) \quad \text{on } \mathcal{T}\times \partial \Omega
\end{aligned}
$$
on a bounded time-space domain $\mathcal{T}\times \Omega$, where $L$ and $M$ are distinct, linear, elliptic differential operators in the spatial variables.
Applying the classic theory for hyperbolic equations (readily available in e.g. Evans, Partial Differential Equations) is not trivial for me, due to the operator $L$ appearing inside the time derivative. So far, I have failed in choosing appropriate eigenfunctions for a Galerkin-Ansatz.
Question: Does anybody know about classic existence results for a problem of this type?

Additional request:
Assuming a special case of $L,M$, where the above equation can be reformulated it into a set of two equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_{t} L u - N v = 0\\
\partial_{t} v + \tilde N u = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $L$ is again an elliptic operator, and $N,\tilde N$ are operators such that the above system is equivalent to the original equation.
If the resulting system is easier to analyse, I am also interested in the same (i.e. existence) results of this particular case.
Many thanks.

Here's what I would try:

Check that for each $t$ and $f \in S$, where $S$ is an appropriately chosen function space, there is a unique solution to the elliptic problem:
$$ L\phi = f \text{ on }\Omega,\ u = h(t)\text{ on }\partial\Omega. $$
Let $S_tf$ denote this solution. The operator $S_t$ is an elliptic pseudo differential operator of order $-s$, where $s$ is the order of $L$.

Let $f_0 = S_0g$.

The system now becomes
\begin{align*}
\partial_{tt}f + MS_tf &= 0\text{ on }[0,T]\times\Omega\\
f &= f_0\text{ on }\{0\}\times\Omega\\
\left.S_tf\right|_{[0,T]\times\partial\Omega} &= h.
\end{align*}

This is a system of pseudodifferential equations. Assuming that the order of $M$ is no more than $s+1$, the system is hyperbolic. In fact, it is simpler, because the top order term is differentiation with respect to $t$ only.

I believe it can be formulated as an ODE on a fixed function space $H$ that can be solved using the standard way to solve an ODE. What I have in mind is defining an integral operator by integrating the left side and reformulating the equation so that a solution is a fixed point of the operator.

Finally, prove the existence of a solution by using a priori estimates (taking advantage of the fact that all of the pseudodifferential operators are elliptic) and applying the standard contraction mapping principle.


It's possible that someone else has already encountered this type of system and written out the details. However, assuming the above argument is viable, it's pretty straightforward to work it all out yourself. I think the most appropriate function spaces would be a Sobolev space $H$ for the elliptic operator and $C^0([0,T],H)$ for the integral equation.

Thank you, I appreciate your answer. Concerning
1-3: I am not familiar with pseudo operators, I will read about them.
Concerning 4-6: In the case of hyperbolicity of $\partial_{tt} + MS_t$ i would have tried to apply the Galerkin method as intended initially. You, however, seem to advise me to build a fixed-point-thm based argument. Why is that?
Further: When you say "integrating the left side... ", do you mean integrating over $\Omega$ the whole equation, or rather something of this kind: $T(f):=\int_0^t MS_t f dt$, st. the equation becomes $\partial_t f(t) - \partial_t f(0) + T(f) = 0$?

You can try Galerkin. I am not familiar with that approach. I was summarizing the standard proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem for an ODE using a contraction map. Since $MS_t$ is a differential operator of negative order, the equation is analytically equivalent to the equation $\partial^2_{tt}f = 0$. By integration, I meant integration with respect to $t$. Since it's second order, you have to either write it as a system of first order equations or integrate twice.

Thank you for your answer.

Dear Mr Yang, I have a follow-up question - could you provide references on where to start reading about "pseudo differential operators"?

I suggest looking at Michael Taylor's books. For example, he shows how to use them for elliptic PDEs in one of the volumes of "Partial Differential Equations". He also has a book devoted to pseudodifferential operators.

Thank you very much!
